# How do I get the beans that spring has registered with jmx?

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

is there a way to get the list of bean instances that spring has registered with the mbeanserver?

I saw that you can register a MBeanExporterListener on the MBeanExporter, but that only tells me the ObjectName that a bean was registered with. Can I use that ObjectName somewhere to get the instance of the Object that was registered?

I see that one option could be to subclass MBeanExporter, but I really don't want to do that unless I have to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't. You have to subclass MBeanExporter if you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I had tested a sample code as follows

```
    // Get the Platform MBean Server
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    // Construct the ObjectName for the MBean we will register
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("com.example.mbeans:type=Hello");
    // Create the Hello World MBean
    Hello mbean = new Hello();
    // Register the Hello World MBean
    mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);

    Set<ObjectInstance> instances = mbs.queryMBeans(name, null);
    ObjectInstance instance = (ObjectInstance) instances.toArray()[0];
    System.out.println("Class Name:t" + instance.getClassName());
    System.out.println("Object Name:t" + instance.getObjectName());

    // Wait forever
    System.out.println("Waiting forever...");
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Of course there is `interface HelloMBean` and

```
class Hello extends NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements HelloMBean
```

The output is

```
Class Name:tcom.example.mbeans.Hello
Object Name:tcom.example.mbeans:type=Hello
Waiting forever...
```

Hope this helps!

**Update :**

`public class ObjectInstance extends Object implements Serializable`. ObjectInstance represent the object name of an MBean and its class name. We cannot retrieve the reference to the object itself.

I guess the only way to operate on the registered mbeans is to use JMS/RMI connector(or HTML adaptors) to get connection of mbaean server, create mbaen proxy using JMX.newMBeanProxy corresponding to registered mbean and invoke methods on that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after the Object instance, not the Class name.

Comment: Once you have the Class Name you can type cast the object to the Class Name and use it : Hello helloObject = (Hello)instance;

Comment: unless I am misunderstanding what you mean, that is not possible in Java.

Comment: Yes I am sorry I take my comment back. A bit of research and i arrived at following conclusion : JMX by spec hides the actual reference to the actual object. You cannot get the object referenece via the JMX API (the MBeanServer won't give you access to it).It seems it is one of the primary goal of JMX.

Comment: I guess the only way to operate on the registered mbeans is to use JMS/RMI connector to get connection of mbaean server, create mbaen proxy using JMX.newMBeanProxy corresponding to registered mbean and invoke methods on that.